# Error while Autowiring a bean component having @Configuration @EnableScheduling @Component annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, autowired

I am working in sprig application
which have a class scheduledJob, having the following annotations

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Component 
public class ScheduledJob {
//code
}
```

I need autowire this to another class notificationServiceImpl. I given

```
@Service
public class NotificationServiceImp implements NotificationService{
  @Autowired
  private ScheduledJob scheduledJob;
//code

}
```

I am getting the following error

```
06:23:36,678 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notificationServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduledJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.storilabs.of.schedules.ScheduledJob' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
06:23:36,688 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notificationServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduledJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.storilabs.of.schedules.ScheduledJob' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) [spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.storilabs.of.schedules.ScheduledJob' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1504) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
```

I am just new to spring. Please help me out in this.

**EDIT**
The scheduled class functions are working perfectly on the the scheduled time. No issues found in that. But my current requirement is to add one more option to trigger this function using an API call. So that I can start a new trigger to send notifications at any time by sending this API call.

I have tried to create a new object without autowiring (I know this is not a good way)

```
ScheduledJob scheduledJob = new ScheduledJob();
```

and calling internal functions like `scheduledJob.function()`
The scheduled class functions are working perfectly on the the scheduled time. No exceptions or anything found while the function workig on the time of scheduled time. If the function call by API call, some null pointer exception was happening while calling some other java object in that function. I think other autowired object may not be initialized at this time

Comment: not sure if you can use Configuration without an @Bean annotation!!!

Comment: It perfectly working all the classes, only issue is happening while autowiring the class scheduledJob. These classes using other autowiring with other classes without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong in the way you are using the @Configuration annotation.
I guess the implementation should be something like below in your case:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Task task() {
        return new Task();
    }
}
```

the @Configuration is responsible for bean creation only. Its kind of xml bean definition replacement if you have used the xml driven configuration before. In the above example it creates a bean that you can autowire in your application.

the real implementation of your scheduled bean can be defined as follows:

```
public class Task {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=2000)
    public void doTask(){
        System.out.println("do some task");
    }
}
```

this really gives you flexibility of your implementation.